# How can I add vertical space to a beamercolorbox to make it align with another one?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, boxes

I'm doing beamer slides in the 16:9 aspect ratio, so I want to use a more horizontal flow than I was when I had 4:3 slides.  For example, I'd like to place a theorem and its proof side-to-side rather than the proof below the theorem.  As in:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{There is no largest prime number}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{theorem}
 There are infinitely many primes.
\end{theorem}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{proof}
 Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.  
 Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.  
 Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.  
 Thus it is prime, but is bigger than $p$.  
 This is a contradiction.
\end{proof}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: sample output]

As you can see, the theorem box is a lot shorter than the proof box and the effect is kind of ugly.  Is there a nice way to add vertical space to the shorter one to make it the same height as the longer one?

Comment: Your proof is wrong ...

Comment: @Hendrik: I'm just copying Till's proof from the beameruserguide.  Mentally substitute lorem ipsum if you like. `:-)`

Comment: @Matthew: [That doesn't make the proof correct](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/96/documentation-bug-in-euclids-proof) (and yes, I did already mentally substitute something that makes more sense `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik: I didn't say it was correct.

Comment: @Matthew: I somewhat guessed that you knew it's incorrect, but I wanted to make this clear to others, just in case.

Comment: If you're coming to tex.sx for your maths knowledge, [you're doing it wrong](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Incidentally, I wanted to do a similar thing but with `<div>`s in html and I was surprised/disappointed it wasn't easier

Comment: @Seamus: If you're coming here for webdesign advice, [you're doing it wrong](http://doctype.com/).

Comment: [I already know the answer for the webdesign context](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight)

Comment: This conversation is hilarious!

Comment: But I just learned something new from this: how to make slides in 16:9 aspect ratio. Sad thing, though, is most of the projectors around are still in 4:3 :(

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: Question: What's the quickest way to include part or all of your PDF output when posting a question or answer on this site? How did you do it for this particular question?

Comment: @Jimi: I use TeXShop on the Mac.  You can select a part of the PDF viewer window and copy it.  Then open up Preview and Select File > New.  You'll get a PDF of what you clipped.  Then save it as PNG.

Comment: @Matthew: I'm a TeXShopper, too! Thanks for the info; very helpful!

Comment: @Jimi: Good, I can give more specific tips.  Before you select and copy, make sure you click the dotted rectangle button on the right-hand side of your preview window's toolbar.  That will make the mouse select regions, rather than select text or magnify the document.

Comment: @Matthew: I'm familiar with copying stuff off Preview :) But thanks for the extra tip, and for enlightening me on this in general! So, hopefully, I can begin to post more useful questions/answers.

Comment: @Matthew: See now also the very related question: [How to modify columns/column environments so they resize automatically to the largest column ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/how-to-modify-columns-column-environments-so-they-resize-automatically-to-the-lar/21591#21591).

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I would mark this question as duplicated. What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

I can provide only a hack ...

```
\begin{theorem}
 There are infinitely many primes.\rule[-5\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{0pt}
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

and the complete code to visualize the meaning of the `\normalbaselineskip`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{There is no largest prime number}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{theorem}
 There are infinitely many primes.%
\rule[-1\normalbaselineskip]{10pt}{1pt}\kern-10pt%
\rule[-2\normalbaselineskip]{10pt}{1pt}\kern-10pt%
\rule[-3\normalbaselineskip]{10pt}{1pt}\kern-10pt%
\rule[-4\normalbaselineskip]{10pt}{1pt}\kern-10pt%
\rule[-5\normalbaselineskip]{10pt}{1pt}    
\end{theorem}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{proof}
 Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.  
 Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.  
 Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.  
 Thus it is prime, but is bigger than $p$.  
 This is a contradiction.
\end{proof}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But thanks for the hack, at least.  I hadn't thought about using `\normalbaselineskip` as a unit of length.  That can make guessing-and-checking a quicker process.

Comment: @Herbert Could you explain how your answer works? As I understand it, it creates a widthless, lengthless rule at a certain position, thus forcing the box to stretch to accommodate it. The rule is moved down (hence the minus sign) 5 times the `\normalbaselineskip` which is...? A measure of the vertical height of a line of text? Is that along the right lines?

Comment: @Seamus: I have no idea how much it is. It is not interesting because it is one line and in the proof we have 5 additional lines.

Comment: @Herbert but it is a measure of the height of a line, right? That is what's important.

Comment: @Seamus: yes, from baseline to next baseline and using the default text size.

Comment: @Herbert I think it would be helpful if you included this information in your answer: this site should just be about providing code snippets that produce the desired outcome, good answers should teach people stuff about TeX.

Comment: @Herbert why not `\vspace{4\normalbaselineskip}`?

Comment: @Yannis: Sorry, but why 4 when I have 5 additional lines? see edited example

Comment: @Herbert Using Mathews code on my computer strangely it displays the left line over two lines! MikTeX and TeXworks!

Comment: @Yannis: ok, then you are right. I have   `beamer.cls    2010/06/21 development version 3.10 A class for typesetting ...`

Comment: @Seamus: I would have liked to upvote your last comment, but I think it's missing a crucial "not".

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, you're right. There is a not missing. It should read "this site should **not** be just about providing code snippets..."

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a dummy column seems to work for me

```
\begin{block}{blocktitle}
\begin{columns}
% dummy column
\column{0cm}
~
\setlength{\rest}{0.25\textheight}
\vskip\rest
~
% now real column 
\column{\textwidth} 
words 123 \\
more words\\
\end{columns}
```