# How to modify columns/column environments so they resize automatically to the largest column ?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, columns

This question was originally a duplicate of [How can I add vertical space to a beamercolorbox to make it align with another one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9740/215). The response to that question was to add a vertical space according to the largest column, as Seamus explains in the comments. I would like, however, to do this in an automatic way.

I rephrase my question.

First, here is the original question, which I leave with minor modifications so that the motivation remains clear. Then, I will analyze and explain the new, rephrased question.

---

**Original question**

When using the `columns` environment in beamer, I sometimes find myself with these situation: two columns with some contents (like a `block`) whose height are different. The result is that each element appears with its height:

[image: example of columns]

I think that if both columns had the same height (the max of all columns), the presentation would be more elegant (at least with the presentation that I am currently creating).

Normally I add some `\vspace` with a length determined by trial-and-error. Needless to say, this is an annoying process. I would like to force the contents of a `column` to have the same height as the largest column.

The example above was generated by this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{A block}
        Hello
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Another block}
        This one has a larger height since it has an itemize
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item a
        \item item b
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**New question**

I have examined `beamerbaserequires.sty` looking for the definition of the `columns` and `column` environment. In order to resize each column, I think it is necessary to rewrite part of the code, since a `column` is implemented as a `minipage` without a height parameter. My new question is, as the title says, **How to modify `columns/column` environments so they resize automatically to the largest column ?**

My first thoughts on how to achieve this are the following:

1. Resizing each `column` to the largest one may not be possible with one pass. It is only when the `columns` environment is closed that we could know the correct size and at that time it is too late to modify each column.
2. At the code that "closes" a `column` could add a vertical space equal to the size of the largest `column` so far.
3. The size of the largest column could be written and read from the aux file or some other temporal file, so that, in a second pass, all columns are resized correctly.

These guidelines are probably incorrect, implausible or too difficult to implement, since I  have nearly no experience coding in TeX/LaTeX. Any comments regarding these ideas are welcome as well.

PS.
I hesitate whether this question has become too specific (or even too broad), or if it should become a community wiki...

Comment: I'm pretty sure we've had this sort of question before. The basic answer was "no, the easiest way is to add vspace manually." But there are smart ways of working out exactly how much vspace to add. For example if it's just text, then add the right number of `\baselineskip`s. It's more complex if you've got itemize etc, but still possible to calculate it. (Or use phantom)

Comment: Aha: [found it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9740/215) IS this a duplicate or do you want to make your question more specific?

Comment: @Seamus: Ok, I think that I will rewrite my question focusing on how to change the `columns`/`column` environment so that it does this automatically. PS: sorry I did not respond earlier, I went away for the weekend

Comment: This new question seems worthy of a bounty. Any takers?

Comment: So, basically you seem to want a vertical version of the eqparbox package?

Comment: A vertical version of [eqparbox](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/eqparbox.html) that works with beamer columns/blocks would do the trick, yes...

Comment: I'm just reading your question now. Note that using "resize the column" is still a little confusing, because people which only skim the now quite long question might think your are talking about the width, not the height. I first thought you want some `tabularx` like feature. :-)

Comment: Actually you don't want to resize the `column`s but the `block`s inside them, right? I just started to code something. One question: Must the columns support verbatim material? I have two possible solution in mind and one does it in one compile run but doesn't support verbatim. The other one needs two runs but does support it.

Comment: @Seamus: Here you go!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One way to do this is to collect the whole `columns` content e.g. using the `environ` package, which stores the environment body in `\BODY`. Redefine `column` to measure the natural height of each column as well as remembering the maximum height in a first pass and then typeset the columns in a second pass where a `\vspace` is inserted with the correct adjustment.

I use here a counter to store the heights in unique macros which are then used to define the `\autoheight` macro with the right amount. This `\autoheight` macro must be placed where the extra height is required, e.g. before `\end{box}`. It can and should be placed in all `column`s and will be just `\vspace*{0pt}` for the largest `column`. It would also be possible to add this macro to all `\end{box}`, e.g. using the `etoolbox` package and `\preto{\endbox}{\autoheight}`. Also the `columns` environment could be redefined instead of using `acolumns` so no frame code must be adjusted at all. However, this makes the application less flexible. For example if there are two `box`es in one column both would be resized incorrectly. However, this could also be implemented, e.g. by counting the number of `box`es per `column` and spread the height accordantly. (This is left as exercise to the reader ;-) )

#### Limitations:

- Does not support verbatim content like `lstlistings` even when the `fragile` option is set for the `frame`.
- Does not support cascaded `columns` (yet). This is because some values are set globally.

Both of these could be avoided with some extra effort.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{environ}% Required for \NewEnviron, i.e. to read the whole body of the environment
\makeatletter

\newcounter{acolumn}%  Number of current column
\newlength{\acolumnmaxheight}%   Maximum column height


% `column` replacement to measure height
\newenvironment{@acolumn}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{acolumn}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \@tempdimc=\dimexpr\ht\@tempboxa+\dp\@tempboxa\relax
    % Save height of this column:
    \expandafter\xdef\csname acolumn@height@\roman{acolumn}\endcsname{\the\@tempdimc}%
    % Save maximum height
    \ifdim\@tempdimc>\acolumnmaxheight
        \global\acolumnmaxheight=\@tempdimc
    \fi
}

% `column` wrapper which sets the height beforehand
\newenvironment{@@acolumn}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{acolumn}%
    % The \autoheight macro contains a \vspace macro with the maximum height minus the natural column height
    \edef\autoheight{\noexpand\vspace*{\dimexpr\acolumnmaxheight-\csname acolumn@height@\roman{acolumn}\endcsname\relax}}%
    % Call original `column`:
    \orig@column{#1}%
}{%
    \endorig@column
}

% Save orignal `column` environment away
\let\orig@column\column
\let\endorig@column\endcolumn

% `columns` variant with automatic height adjustment
\NewEnviron{acolumns}[1][]{%
    % Init vars:
    \setcounter{acolumn}{0}%
    \setlength{\acolumnmaxheight}{0pt}%
    \def\autoheight{\vspace*{0pt}}%
    % Set `column` environment to special measuring environment
    \let\column\@acolumn
    \let\endcolumn\end@acolumn
    \BODY% measure heights
    % Reset counter for second processing round
    \setcounter{acolumn}{0}%
    % Set `column` environment to wrapper
    \let\column\@@acolumn
    \let\endcolumn\end@@acolumn
    % Finally process columns now for real
    \begin{columns}[#1]%
        \BODY
    \end{columns}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  \begin{acolumns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{A block}
        Hello
        \autoheight
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Another block}
        This one has a larger height since it has an itemize
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item a
        \item item b
        \end{itemize}
        \autoheight
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{acolumns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Brilliant. That's a contender for the TeX.sx package, surely?

Comment: @Seamus: Sure. I like to get some suggestions for the to be used user interface.

Comment: +1 Excellent! Sorry I've been quiet even though I was the OP, I was away for some weeks.

Comment: @MartinScharrer there's a little problem with spaces with your solution, see [acolumns environment modifies columns widths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54398). David Carlisle solved it, is it ok if I update your answer?

Comment: @capitalaslash: Thanks for notifying me. I made the change now.