# All blocks of beamerposter should be of same height

Tags: beamer, columns, beamerposter, block

I will greatly appreciate your help with this question.

I use `beamerposter` and want all the blocks (across various columns) to be of the same height (= max height of among all other blocks).

I came across your solution here:
[How to modify columns/column environments so they resize automatically to the largest column ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/how-to-modify-columns-column-environments-so-they-resize-automatically-to-the-la)

However, in case of `beamerposter`, blocks can be located in different columns.
And this trick of placing blocks inside columns and count the height does not work here.

I need somehow to fetch all blocks of all columns of the poster and compute max height (and set each block height to this value, maybe a certain parameter for blocks ?).

I imagine there should be a way to re-use a solution from here:
[How to modify columns/column environments so they resize automatically to the largest column ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/how-to-modify-columns-column-environments-so-they-resize-automatically-to-the-la)

by nesting blocks into special dummy columns  to count them and to adjust their height.
I tried to play around this idea but failed in my tryings.

Can you please suggest a solution here?
I will greatly appreciate your help with this question.

Thank you
/ John

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.