How can I make a tcolorbox round its south corners if its bottom is close enough to the bottom of the page?
I'm making a document with triangular footers around the outer corner of the page, where the page number is. If a tcolorbox is too tall and too close to the bottom, it can be cut off by these footers.
How can I make it so that "rounded corners" is "south" if the distance between frame.south and current page.south is smaller than the height of the footer but "" if it isn't?
Below is an example code that showcases my problem; note how the big triangle covers the colorbox:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Setup for fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{%The Left style footer is on Odd pages
        % Get the number of pages, and calculate what percentage of the way through the book we are
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            % Two nodes to make the triangles in the corner
            % Note the use of thepagepercent to change the color from red to black
            \node[style=isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=120, fill=red, anchor=west, minimum height=5cm, rotate=90] (base) at (current page.south west) {};
            % Page number goes in the corner
            \node[anchor=south west, xshift=1em, yshift=1.5em] (num) at (current page.south west) {\Large\textbf{\textcolor{white}{[\thepage]}}};;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \fancyfoot[RE]{%The Right style footer is on Even pages
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            % Two nodes to make the triangles in the corner
            % Note the use of thepagepercent to change the color from red to black
            \node[style=isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=120, fill=red, anchor=west, minimum height=5cm, rotate=90] (base) at (current page.south east) {};
            % Page number goes in the corner
            \node[anchor=south east, xshift=-1em, yshift=1.5em] (num) at (current page.south east) {\Large\textbf{\textcolor{white}{[\thepage]}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=red, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \LARGE\textbf{CORE SYSTEM}
        \Large\textbf{VENGEANCE OF GAIA}
        \\
        \normalsize\textit{
        Hounded by enemies superior in numbers and technology, the Hercynian people have learned to rely on maximum exploitation of advantageous terrain and the element of surprise as force multipliers. When encroaching on their land, every bush has ears, and every glint in the jungle canopy might be the lens of a scope trained on its target.}
        
        \blindtext
        \blindtext
        \blindtext
        \blindtext
        \blindtext
        \blindtext
        
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=green, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
            \textbf{Conceal Position}\\
            \normalsize{ Passive, Free Action }\\
            At the end of its turn, if it hasn't made any \textbf{Attacks} or forced any \textbf{Saves}, the Antlion can \textbf{Hide} as a \textbf{free action}.
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.001,opacitybacktitle=0.001,colback=white,size=fbox, colframe=orange, boxrule=2pt, box align=top]
            \textbf{Decapitating Strike}\\
            \normalsize{ Active (1CP), Protocol, Efficient }\\
            This action can only be taken while \textbf{Hidden}. Your next \textbf{Weapon Attack} before the start of your next turn gains +1d3 \textbf{bonus damage} for every \textbf{Accuracy} {+} \textbf{Die} which affects the final roll.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    }
    \end{multicols}
                        
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

[EDIT] I found someone who had a related problem: they wanted to make two columns automatically have the same height. The question was answered with a piece of code that can save the height of a column through the use of the Environ package.
However, I don't understand the underlying concepts, so I could really use an explanation from someone more knowledgeable.

Can you please add some code, which compiles and shows both your achievement and roadblock? Thank you

I mean I gueass but I don't see how it could help

There you go. Does this help any?

I found an answered question here that might point us to a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/how-to-modify-columns-column-environments-so-they-resize-automatically-to-the-la
Problem is I don't understand the underlying concepts. Do you think you could explain to me how to adapt this solution for my needs?

The way I'm using Figure I always know on which page it ends up, and even if I didn't it wouldn't matter because those triangles are in the corner of every page.
Also the example code is somewhat misleading because the way I use them those boxes never spill beyond the page: they just get too close to it.
Could you give me an actual piece of code you think might work? At least as a base to iterate on?

Ok, let's assume I take the box out of the figure. What can I do in that case?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

off-topic: you really shouldn't end lines with \\ .

we should clean up these comments ... please do clarify in your question, though, whether you actually have nothing but the box on the page (and don't need figure).

In the version here I used a tcolorbox, but in the actual document the hierarchy is:
figure{tikzpicture{node{tcolorbox}; node{tcolorbox{tcolrobox}};}}
